# CUDA equivalent of OpenCL CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR

Tags: cuda, opencl, gpgpu

I'd like to know if there is something similar to `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR` but for CUDA. Reading the CUDA docs it seems the only "zero-copy" functionality is implemented through the API function `cudaHostAlloc`. The problem is that CUDA allocates the memory and there is no way for me to divert it to some preallocated CPU memory area. A thing that is normal with OpenCL using the specificied flag for `clCreateBuffer`.

Maybe I am wrong, but it looks like CUDA doesn't implement such a thing at all.

Comment: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1ge8d5c17670f16ac4fc8fcb4181cb490c

Answer (score 3):

> The problem is that CUDA allocates the memory and there is no way for me to divert it to some preallocated CPU memory area.

The API call that does that in CUDA is `cudaHostRegister()`, see [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1ge8d5c17670f16ac4fc8fcb4181cb490c).

It takes a pointer returned by an ordinary host allocator such as `malloc()` or `new`, and converts the memory region into pinned memory.  (Which would be suitable for "zero-copy" usage, among other things.)